# What do brackets (instead of no brackets) mean when you pass a series in pd.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Perhaps a very basic syntactical question here but I haven’t been able to find an answer:

why, when you take a basic series (series_sample_name) and write df_sample_name = pd.DataFrame(series_sample_name) do you get basically the same output as the series but in df form, whereas if you write pd.DataFrame([series_sample_name]) you would get the series values displayed horizontally and the index labels become columns? I wasn’t aware that adding single brackets to a single object, when you only pass that one object, had meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question. When you put square brackets around anything in Python, it will be interpreted as a list. As you can see below, one is a pandas series and it [inherits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) the attributes from that class. Now, a list is a different class and inherits different attributes.

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
ser = pd.Series(data=d, index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(type(ser))
print(type([ser]))
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'list'>
```